# Is there any tool to draw 3D map/floor map using open GL

Tags: opengl, 3d

Is there any tool available which can be use to draw 3D floor plan /Map which gives the code o/p in open GL??

What I want to do is to draw a 3D map of my floor.

Comment: "o/p"?  Can't say I've seen that before.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be to hard to draw your floor plan in a basic 3D modelling package like [Wings3D](http://www.wings3d.com/), export to a basic format like [.obj](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) that could be easily parsed.

[image: Wings 3D interface]

If you need a 3D package with more options(for texturing,baking lights, etc.) give [Blender](http://www.blender.org/download/get-blender/) a try. There are plenty of export options, including .raw (Raw faces) which 
an even more basic way to store vertices/faces than .obj. Also it's fairly easy to write
a custom exporter using Blender's Python API which gives you the OpenGL code the way you need it for your setup.

[image: Blender 3D Interface]